# Can ENCFS container be mounted from live disk?

Tags: mount, livecd, encfs

I have a problem with my Linux Mint installation. So I'm thinking of backing up my files from a Linux Mint 17 live disk (which I'm using right now to post this). I'd like to back up my encfs container, but don't know how to do so without mounting it and copy the contents to an external drive. Is this possible, and how to do it?

I use the following command to mount the container:

`encfs ~/.zzz_encfs ~/zzz`

But how to tell the live disk terminal where to look for it? I cd'ed to my home directory and ran the command but it returns the error `Unable to locate root directory, aborting.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory `~/.zzz_encfs` is located in your home directory. In the shell, `~` at the beginning of a path represents your home directory.

If your live system mounts filesystems of your disk automatically, check the GUI or run `cat /proc/mounts` to see where they may be mounted. Usually the mount points are sudirectories of `/media` or subdirectories of subdirectories of `/media`.

By default, your home directory is at the location `/home/user8547` on the installed system, where `user8547` is your username. If you have a separate partition for `/home`, your home directory is `/user8547` on that partition.

Once you've located your home directory, create an empty directory anywhere you like, or use the existing `zzz` directory in your home directory if you like. Then run

```
encfs /path/to/home/directory/.zzz_encfs /path/to/empty/directory
```

e.g. it may be something like

```
encfs /media/sda1/home/user8547/.zzz_encfs /media/sda1/home/user8547/zzz
```

.

Comment: This is the full path where the encfs container is stored: `/media/mint/4b8f3e82-168c-435a-b762-d77f51052fa8/home/user8547/.zzz_encfs`. So far I haven't had any luck mounting it. I may be incorrectly reading your directions. ENCFS is installed and I've tried mounting the container with root privileges, but no luck.

Comment: @user8547 What happens when you run `encfs /media/mint/4b8f3e82-168c-435a-b762-d77f51052fa8/home/user8547/.zzz_encfs /media/mint/4b8f3e82-168c-435a-b762-d77f51052fa8/home/user8547/encfs`?

Comment: Tx! I cd'ed to the user8547 directory in terminal and successfully ran the command.